# Manually highlight a specific section in javascript SyntaxHighlighter

Tags: javascript, css, syntax-highlighting

I am using the [Syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) library to display code on a webpage. I would like to highlight certain sections of code in response to various events on the page. It may be a single character, or a multiple line section, but it will always be a contiguous section of text.

I know that SyntaxHighlighter has functionality to highlight individual lines, but I need a little more fine grained control than that.

I know the selection start and selection length points in the original source code, but the highlighter has inserted a lot of html elements, so it is a bit difficult to find those indexes again to wrap them in another tag.

Is there a good way I can override existing formatting, and apply my own css to a specific portion of the text? Is there a different syntax highlighting plugin that may give me what I need?

Comment: Hey CMP, a sample/example might help..

Comment: Basically, I have a section of code in a <pre> tag, exactly like the examples on that site. I would like to highlight a specific word programatically to be black text with a yellow background, overriding any formatting the syntax highlighter has already done. I have seen examples of syntax highlighting, and of highlighting arbitrary text, but never both together.

Comment: Updated, tell me if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about running the generated markup through a function that searches and replaces the specific 'programmatic word' with,

```
<span class="customHighlight">word</span>
```

..and you can style it as follows,

```
span.customHighlight {
  background:#FAFAD2;
  color:#000;
}
```

I sort of worry about the efficiency of this though.

**EDIT**: I've got something, if you look at the source of the script relative to the highlighter for a language (here, CSS), http://alexgorbatchev.com.s3.amazonaws.com/pub/sh/3.0.83/scripts/shBrushCss.js,

```
        { regex: /!important/g,
          css: 'color3' },  // !important
```

..which renders as,

```
<code class="css color3">!important</code>
```

..so, just define your 'word' as a rule with an equivalent CSS declaration.

Comment: Doesn't this completely defeat the point of using a syntax highlighter in the first place, though?

Comment: Well yeah; alternatively I'd waddle through the highlighter's source. I'm looking through it right now..

Comment: I like the idea of embedding it in the source code. I am not necessarily highlighting a particular word though, it is any arbitrary position in the code. I could definitely wrap it in something regexable though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery as in example http://www.tripbase.com/code/highlightTutorial.html. According to me provide a textbox and onchange event send the highlighted text to the function and the function will highlight the text

For your highlight and un-highlight jquery just visit bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Comment: That is useful, but it is not so easy anymore to find the exact text I am looking for, because the syntax highlighter has already changed the div contents from my original source to something with a lot more markup in between. It is no longer so easy as a regex search.

Comment: Found the proper solution for your highlight and un-highlight jquery just visit http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html